# Tablesorter Jquery library is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I'm having troubles getting the Jquery Tablesorter plugin to work, nothing happens when I click on the column headers. I'm using django to fill the rows. Heres the code:

```
<!-- Load jQuery if not already loaded. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Load the TableSorter plugin. -->
<script src="{% static 'mainApp/jquery.tablesorter.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $("#feedbackTable").tablesorter();
    }); 
    </script>

<!-- Load a theme i.e. "ice". -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.5/css/theme.ice.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...


<table id="feedbackTable" class="tablesorter table table-dark  table-hover sortable" >
                        <thead class="thead-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="cursor: pointer;" >Submitted By <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                                <th style="cursor: pointer;" >Category <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                                <th style="cursor: pointer;" >Date Added <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                                <th style="display:none;" >Feedback</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% block content %}
                                {% for feedback in feedbacks %}
                            <tr style="cursor: pointer;" @click="showFeedback = !showFeedback"> 
                                <td >{{feedback.submitted_by}}</td>
                                <td  >
                                    {{feedback.type_choice}}
                                </td>
                                <!--<td>{{feedback.feedback}}</td>-->
                                <td>{{feedback.created_at}}</td>
                                <td style="display:none;">  {{feedback.feedback}}</td>
                            </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endblock content %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Do you get errors in your console?

Comment: Nope, no errors.

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle?